# Flight search for road trip

Tags: flight-search-engines

I want to make a road trip in Italy.
This is what I know:

- My departure city (Paris)
- My destination country (Italy, no specific city)
- My departure and return dates to Paris.

Everything in between is free.

I am wondering how to find the cheapest flights TO and BACK from Italy, regardless of the city.

Comment: Maybe this allready helps...it's a little hard, but you can click your way through in Google Flights map-view: https://www.google.com/flights/#search;f=CDG,ORY,BVA,XHP,XPG;d=2017-10-12;r=2017-10-16;mc=m;q=flights Got nothing better in mind, still interested in a better solution for something like that.

Comment: Skyscanner allows you to enter country name, not only airport.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to expand Top Questions answer as I think that the Google flights seems to be the most easiest and straight forward way how to do this (I use it for the same thing as you want to).
Go to google flights and pick your departure city (Paris) and destination (Italy) and go to the map (Explore Destinations - red box).

[image: italy1]

Map view opens where you can check all possible destinations. Use filters (red box) to narrow down your options.

[image: italy2]

**Edit** As it is not possible to input country in the Origin, then a "workaround" could be to use "Nearby airports" (red box). You can, however, put only 5 of them, still it is possible to cover the biggest airports of a country (additionaly it shows cheapest price for *most* airports in the list).

[image: italy3]

Comment: +1, I didn't take the time for a answer, just wanted to point to google. But some other searchengine for the purpose of OP would be interesting, too.

Comment: I heard of Google Flights, but did not know the Map View, it's awesome!
Although it does not solve the second part of the equation, which maybe is harder, the return flight: Fly from ANYWHERE in Italy and land in Paris.
It does not support country name for the departure city.

Comment: @nute that is true, I forgot that. I usually use the "workaround" I added to the reply now.